# How to display more field from parent class in razor view from dbmodel in asp net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

**DBModel:**

This class has relationship with **About** class. The structure of class **Balance** has shown below.

```
public partial class Balance
{
    public int recId { get; set; }
    public float chargeAmount { get; set; }
    //relationship
    public virtual About About { get; set; }
}
```

The **About** class structure is shown as below:

```
public partial class About
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public About()
    {
        this.Balance= new HashSet<Balance>();
    }
    public int recId { get; set; }
    public float Description { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Balance> Balance{ get; set; }


}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.recId, "categoryCode", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("recId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.recId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.recId= new SelectList(db.About, "recId", "recId");

            return View();
        }
```

I want more field from **About** Model whenever user select value from dropdown in create forms dynamically. Like this:

[image: Explaination]

Comment: Your current code will throw an exception because you are not setting `ViewBag.recId` in your action method, but your view code is trying to render a SELECT element using that. For your original question, you need to make an ajax call to server on the `change` event of the SELECT element and get the details (pass the rec id)

Comment: @shyju I have updated it. thanks for identifying it.

Comment: What more field you want from About ? You have to be specific.

Comment: when user select a value from drop down i want to display on the relevant field on the view and then user can enter value for balance class.

Comment: Listen to the change event on the SELECT and use ajax to get the needed info from server

Comment: how can i perform this particularly as i have tried this approved but failed.

Comment: You have the share the code you tried and failed, explain specifically which part did not work and then people can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170163/discussion-between-alishah-momin-and-shyju).